# Why am i getting unexpected behaviour with the number i copied from my logs

Tags: javascript, numbers

I copied the number ‭7549495‬ from my Laravel log file, this is actually part of a message which I send from textlocal (a messaging service). While sending the message it said your message is invalid. So after looking at all possible issues I copied this number and tried to find its length and I saw some unexpected behaviour.

I copied this number in the browser console and tried to write it as a string and find its length it showed length as 9 even though it has only 7 digits then in another variable I took the same number but this time instead of copying it directly I typed the number and this time I got the length as 7 which is correct. (Screenshot is attached.)

I think while copying the number some special character also gets copied but if it is so then why that extra character is not visible
Please explain why this behaviour occurs, Thanks.

**Number is:** ‭7549495‬

(I copied and pasted this number directly from my logs, you please copy it from here maybe you can recreate that same issue on your end)

[image: Screenshot attached]

Comment: There is a whitespace character (obviously cannot be seen) before and after the number that you have pasted. Can't say why your logs are generating it, but make sure your charset is UTF-8 or some similar standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your number has character [`0x202D`](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x202D/index.html) (left-to-right override) at the beginning and [`0x202C`](https://unicodemap.org/details/0x202C/index.html) (pop directional formatting) at the end. Here's how I determined that:

```js
console.log(
  [..."‭7549495‬"].map(c => "0x" + c.codePointAt(0).toString(16).padStart(2, "0"))
);
```

Comment: Super invisible characters, they are not shown even at jsFiddle editor, which usually shows all invisible characters.

Comment: @Teemu - :-) `vim` shows 'em. But these days I just do a loop like the above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks :)